# Flutter MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, user-permissions, flutter-release

Having issue in release mode of the APK only, in debug mode it is working fine.
After too much of struggling I got issue is coming due to uses of two plugin file_picker & permission_handler If I remove anyone of that, It is working but I need to use both plugins
Please help me out from this issue if anyone know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by simply adding two line of the code in `app/build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false //add this line &
            minifyEnabled false // this line
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

In my case, It is working hope it will be helpful